# Rails polymorphic types and associations. How to change object type/class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'am trying to change polymorphic object type for existing object without any success. I think it unhappens because model has an association with another model.
I'm using Rails 4.1.7

I have some models like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    TYPES = %w(Internal External)
    belongs_to :group
    validates :group, presence: true
end

class User::Internal < User
    belongs_to :group, :class_name => 'Group::Internal'
end

class User::External < User
    belongs_to :group, :class_name => 'Group::External'
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
    TYPES = %w(Internal External)
    has_many :users
end
```

And I've tryied to change existing internal user to external with this code:

```
extgroup = Group.find(5)
myuser = User.find(105)
myuser.becomes! User::External
myuser.type="User::External"
myuser.group = extgroup
```

After this I've got error message: ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch Group::Internal expected, got Group::External

How can I change user type in this example?

Comment: Try setting the user's group_id column manually before calling .becomes!.

Comment: need to see code for becomes! , also how your directory structure looks in models .

Comment: It's a standard method for ActiveRecord: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-becomes-21

Comment: The directory structure is:
    app  
        models  
            user  
                internal.rb  
                external.rb  
            group  
                internal.rb  
                external.rb  
            user.rb  
            group.rb